# How do you set up a continuous deployment pipeline on AWS for a NodeJS project?

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline

I am using Elastic Beanstalk to serve my NodeJS application. It is working perfectly fine when I manually deploy by generating a .zip archive of the projects source code. The zip file *literally* contained:

```
\dist
server.js
request-map.js
credentials.json
```

Now I am trying to set up a continuous deployment pipeline as per: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/continuous-deployment-pipeline/. The deployment  succeeds, but when I navigate to my application I see:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/app/current/dist/wisesheet/index.html'
```

The tutorial does not contain a build stage, and I'm thinking this is the issue - how does the pipeline know what artifacts to deploy? Of course directly in the repo there is no dist folder because nothing has been built yet. So how can it know what to deploy after I push a change into the production branch?

The git repository code structure is as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a Build Stage with a CodeBuild Action before deploy action.

In CodeBuild service, the buildspec is a file which lists commands to build your project. The artifacts section is very important as the files/folders you mention here will be zipped and fed to the next stage (yourdeploy stage)

version: 0.2

```
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - npm install -g typescript
  build:
    commands:
      - tsc index.ts
artifacts:
  files:
    - index.js
```

I found this resource which you may find helpful when adding the build stage:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/build-test-deploy-node-js-app-with-codecommit-codepipeline-codebuild-elastic-beanstalk-c6d89f971ef2